# How to query from a date list in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, hibernateexception

I am trying to query all the transactions happened from a list of dates.So I tried the below function:

```
 public Collection<Transaction> getTransactionsByDates(short status,List<Date> dates){
   Query query = em.createQuery(" SELECT a FROM Transaction a where a.Status=:status and a.dates in :transactionDate");
   query.setParameter("status", status);
   query.setParameter("dates", dates);
   return (Collection<Transaction>) query.getResultList();
}
```

But this throws the error of

> org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: dates

Am I querying in JPA properly?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: seems like there is issue in setting the parameter . Change this    query.setParameter("date", dates);
 to    query.setParameter("transactionDate", dates);

Comment: You wrote `:transactionDate` but then you try to replace the parameter `dates`. Try to change `:transactionDate` in `:dates`. You may also need to use parenthesis around the list `(:dates)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is typo

```
public Collection<Transaction> getTransactionsByDates(short status,List<Date> dates){
   Query query = em.createQuery(" SELECT a FROM Transaction a where a.Status=:status and a.dates in :transactionDate");
   query.setParameter("status", status);
   query.setParameter("transactionDate", dates);
   return (Collection<Transaction>) query.getResultList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace line

> query.setParameter("dates", dates);

with

> query.setParameter("transactionDate", dates);

typo issue